# Convert $A - BAB$ to matrix multiplications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices, $A$ which is diagonal, and $B$ which is hermitian, $1$-sparse--- meaning that every row & column has only 1 element--- and every entry is $1$.

I want to rewrite $A - BAB$ as just matrix multiplications, but can't figure out how to.

I've tried the following:

$A - BAB = ABB - BAB \;$ because $BB = 1$ (where $1$ is the identity matrix).

$ABB - BAB = (AB - BA)B = (A^TB^T - BA)B = ((BA)^T - BA)B$

But this method doesn't seem to be taking me anywhere. Anyone have any tips on where to go from here? Is this problem even solvable?

Some example B's are below:

$
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
$
$
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
$
$
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
$

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what $B$ might look like?

Comment: @JamieBallingall I think OP means that $B$ is a permutation matrix?

Comment: @Aaron I don't think I'm providing just a permutation matrix. It is a hermitian permutation matrix.

Comment: @JamieBallingall I provided some examples in the question; thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Loic What exactly do you mean by writing $A - BAB$ "as just matrix multiplications"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Writing/factoring it in a way such that there are no matrix addition or subtraction operations. Transpose operations and power of a matrix is fine.

Comment: I believe there are no matrices $P$ and $Q$ independent of $A$ such that $A - BAB = PAQ$ for all $A$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Oh, do you have logic to demonstrate that claim?

Comment: Also, are they independent of $B$ as well?

Comment: I allowed $P$ and $Q$ to be dependent on $B$. As for my reasoning, it doesn't work in the 2x2 case, and it seems like adding dimensions will only make things worse, not better.

Comment: @eyeballfrog After re-reading your original comment, I’m not sure why  $A - BAB \neq PAQ$ implies that $A - BAB$ cannot be written as any matrix multiplication (dependent on A and B). Shouldn’t it be “ Does $A - BAB = PQ$ where $P$ and $Q$ are some multiplications of $A$ and $B$ along with some constant matrices.” I think allowing $B$ to have operations performed on it such as addition and subtraction within this string needs to also be allowed in order to have a chance of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible, and we can demonstrate why with a 2x2 example by looking at rank.

If $A=\operatorname{diag}(a_1, a_2)$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then $A-BAB=\operatorname{diag}(a_1-a_2, a_2-a_1)$.  If $a_2=0, a_1\neq 0$, then $A$ is rank $1$, $A-BAB$ is rank 2, and so there cannot exist any $P, Q$ such that $A-BAB=PAQ$

More generally, by a permuting the basis, in dimension $2n+k$, we will have $A=\operatorname{diag}(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \ldots, a_n, b_n, c_1, \ldots, c_k)$ and $A-BAB=\operatorname{diag}(a_1-b_1, b_1-a_1, a_2-b_2, b_2-a_2, \ldots, a_n-b_n, b_n-a_n, 0, 0, \ldots 0)$.  This can be higher rank than $A$, so there would not exist $P, Q$ such that it equaled $PAQ$, let alone $P$ and $Q$ that depended on $A$ and $B$ in a nice way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder if this is possible for the case of a matrix $A$ that has only non-zero entries on the diagonal (implying that the rank of the matrix is $N$ if $A$ is $N \times N$).

Comment: @LoicStoic If $A$ is inverttible, then for ANY $C$, we can always find $P$ and $Q$ such that $PA=AQ=C$, simply take $P=CA^{-1}$ or $Q=A^{-1}C$, but that is probably not what you want, as you want $P$ and $Q$ to be defined in terms of $A$ and $B$ in some reasonable way.

Comment: Yes--- I think the problem then becomes $PAQ = BAB$ such that $P$ and $Q$ are independent of $A$, and $A^{-1}$ exists.