# Rewrite $A - BAB$ as a series of matrix multiplication operations, given $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564571/convert-a-bab-to-matrix-multiplications) question--- which has an elegant answer.

The question was this:

Given a diagonal matrix, $A$, and a Hermitian permutation matrix, $B$, factor $A - BAB$ to $PAQ$, such that $P$ and $Q$ only include $A$ as a matrix multiplication operation, or are independent of $A$.

The answer to that question proved that this was impossible for the case of any diagonal matrix $A$--- but relied on $A$ being non-invertible. Essentially, if $A$ was non invertible, and was $N \times N$, it had a rank $R < N$. The rank of $A - BAB$ had a possibility of having a rank of $N$. Thus $PAQ$ could not exist for that case.

However, it is reasonable to assume an invertible $A$, and also all the entries of $A$ are positive. Is this factorization possible in the case?

Comment: Isn't any linear function has a matrix times vector representation in finite bases? Sorry if not helping directly, but I'm seeing 2 linear functions here, need to look into my notes

Comment: @rych Yes, I think that is true. The matrix $A−BAB$ can be represented as a matrix multiplication. What i’m asking though, is how this decomposition can be computed (i.e.) what should P and Q look like, such that $P$ and $Q$ are not dependent on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a $PAQ$ exists while keeping the matrices shape $N \times N$ but if you're open to reshaping/rearranging* your matrix $A$, and notice that in your case, $BAB$ simply switches diagonal elements of $A$ (permuting the rows when pre-multiplying and the same indexed columns when post-multiplying as $B$ is symmetric), then you could rewrite your expression as simply $(I-B)a$, where $a=\text{diag}(A)$ is a vector made of the diagonal elements of A.

(*) See for example how they find a matrix expression for the transpose operator here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4187135/73934